# Set (0,0) location in psychopy to be left

Tags: python, screen, psychopy

Im trying to present stimuli on screen in psychopy.

Is there a way to set (0,0) to be top/bottom left instead of center?

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to use normalised units:

> In normalised (‘norm’) units the window ranges in both x and y from -1 to +1. That is, the top right of the window has coordinates (1,1), the bottom left is (-1,-1).

If you *really* need 0,0 to be bottom left, then you can just map from one coordinate to another, i.e. something like:

```
def map_coord(x, y):
   return x-1, y-1
```

[psychopy docs](http://www.psychopy.org/general/units.html)

Comment: +1 but this approach actually works for all units. Pixels, degrees, cm, etc. but for these, you need to subtract a screen-dependent number instead of 1, e.g. `return(x - 1920/2, y - 1080/2)` for pixels.